# Django form not submit data

Tags: django, django-forms

need your assistance in figuring out what is wrong with a form in my django app,i have a tab section in my app that has three tabs (lesson,workbook,answer).The work flow is that a user goes through some lesson content then clicks on a "take exercise" button which leads him to the workbook tab.Here i have questions which can either be multiple choice question or easy question depending on the lesson, after completing exercise a user submits the question and he transitions to the answers tab where his submitted answer is displayed in addition to the expected answer if he was wrong.My problem is that when the submit button is clicked the answers are not submitted and hence no user answers are displayed in the answer tab.

Here is the html code

```
<div class="tabs present-addition">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li {% if active_tab == "lesson" %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="#lesson" data-toggle="tab">Lesson Content</a></li>
                                <li {% if active_tab == "workbook" %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="#workbook" data-toggle="tab">Workbook</a></li>
                                <li {% if active_tab == "answers" %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="#answers" data-toggle="tab">Answers</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            {% if messages %}
                            <div>{{ message }}</div>
                            <!--<ul class="messages">
                              {% for message in messages %}
                              <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </ul>-->
                            {% endif %}

                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="lesson">
                                    <p>{{ lesson.content|safe }}</p>

                                    <!--<p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalStyle2">View Example</a></p>-->

                                    {% if lesson.instructions_before %}
                                    <h3>Instructions</h3>
                                    <p>{{ lesson.instructions_before|safe }}</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                <div class="btn-container btn-container-info" id="wkbck">
                                         <a class="btn btn-info btn--minimal btn-lg-bordered btn-inverse" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#workbook" >Take Exercise</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="tab-pane" id="workbook">

                                    {% if lesson.get_exercises %}
                                    {% for exercise in lesson.get_exercises %}
                                        <h4>{{ exercise.title }}</h4>

                                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'exercise_submit' lesson.id exercise.id %}" class="contact" style="text-align:left;">
                                        {% csrf_token %}

                                        <input type="hidden" id="exercise_id" name="exercise_id" value="{{ exercise.id }}">

                                        {% for question in exercise.question_set.all %}
                                            <h6>{{ question.title }}</h6>
                                            {% for answer in question.num_of_expected_answers|get_range %}
                                                {{ forloop.counter }}: <input type="text" name="qu-{{ question.id }}-{{ forloop.counter }}" id="answer-{{ question.id }}-{{ forloop.counter }}" class="contact__field" style="width: 50%;" required /></br>
                                            {% endfor %}                                                                        
                                        {% endfor %}

                                        {% for mcquestion in exercise.multichoicequestion_set.all %}
                                            <h6>{{ mcquestion.title }}</h6>

                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                            {% for option in mcquestion.multichoicequestionoption_set.all %}
                                                {% with forloop.counter as curr_counter %} 
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="mcq-{{ mcquestion.id }}-{{ curr_counter }}" name="mcq-{{ mcquestion.id }}-{{ curr_counter }}" value="{{ option.content }}" >
                                                <label for="mcq-{{ mcquestion.id }}-{{ curr_counter }}">{{ option.content }}</label>
                                                {% endwith %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            </div>

                                            </br>
                                        {% endfor %}

                                        {% for essay_question in exercise.essayquestion_set.all %}
                                            <h6>{{ essay_question.title }}</h6>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <textarea rows="6" cols="50" class="contact__field contact__area" style="width: 50%;" name="eq-{{ essay_question.id }}" id="eq-{{ essay_question.id }}" placeholder="Type your answer here" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            </br>                                                        
                                        {% endfor %}

                                        <div class="btn-container btn-container-info">
                                            <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-info btn--minimal btn-lg-bordered btn-inverse" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#answers" >Submit</button>
                                        </div>

                                        </form>
                                    {% endfor %} 
                                    {% endif %}

                                            <p>
                <!--<div class="btn-container btn-container-info">
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn--minimal btn-lg-bordered btn-inverse" href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                </div>-->
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="answers">
                                    <h4>Exercise Answers</h3>                                    

                                    <!-- Display normal question answers -->
                                    {% if questions and answers %}
                                        {% for question in questions %}
                                            <h6><b>{{ question.title }}</b></h6>
                                            {% if answers %}
                                                <ol>
                                                {% for answer in answers %}
                                                    {% if answer.question.id == question.id %}
                                                    <li>{{ answer.answer }}</li>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                                </ol>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <h6>Expected Answer</h6>
                                            <p>{{ question.expected_answer|safe }}</p>
                                            <hr/>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    <!-- Display multichoice question answers -->
                                    {% if multichoice_questions and mc_answers %}
                                        {% for mc_question in multichoice_questions %}
                                            <h6><b>{{ mc_question.title }}</b></h6>
                                            {% if mc_answers %}
                                                {% for mc_answer in mc_answers %}
                                                    {% if mc_answer.question.id == mc_question.id %}
                                                    <p>{{ mc_answer.selected_choice }}</p>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <h6>Expected Answer</h6>
                                            <p>{{ mc_question.expected_answer|safe }}</p>
                                            <hr/>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    <!-- Display essay question answers -->
                                    {% if essay_questions and eq_answers %}
                                        {% for es_question in essay_questions %}
                                            <h6><b>{{ es_question.title }}</b></h6>
                                            {% if eq_answers %}
                                                {% for eq_answer in eq_answers %}
                                                    {% if eq_answer.question.id == es_question.id %}
                                                    <p>{{ eq_answer.answer }}</p>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <h6>Expected Answer</h6>
                                            <p>{{ es_question.expected_answer|safe }}</p>
                                            <hr/>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}

                                    <!-- This exercise has not been answered -->                                    
                                    {% if not answers and not mc_answers and not eq_answers %}
                                    <p>Will be revealed after submitting your work.</p>
                                    {% endif %}

                                    <!-- Show next lesson button if available -->
                                    {% if answers or mc_answers or eq_answers %}
                                        {% if lesson.next_lesson %}
                                        <p>
                                            <div class="btn-container btn-container-warning">
                                                <a class="btn btn-warning btn--minimal btn-lg-bordered btn-inverse" href="{% url 'learn_lesson' lesson.next_lesson.module.course.slug lesson.next_lesson.module.slug lesson.next_lesson.slug %}">Next Lesson</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </p>                                    
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end tabs -->
```

Here is the view.py

```
 def lesson_exercise_posted(request, lesson_id, exercise_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LessonExerciseForm(request.POST)
        lesson = Lesson.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
        exercise = Exercise.objects.get(pk=exercise_id)
        exercise_submission, created = ExerciseSubmission.objects.get_or_create(
                                                 student=request.user,
                                                 #lesson=lesson,
                                                 exercise=exercise)

        if created:
            for key in request.POST.iterkeys():
                value = request.POST.get(key)
                print("{0}:::{1}".format(key, value))

                if value:
                    # Get Link Questions; Can be more than one
                    if key.startswith('qu'):
                        prefix, question_id, question_counter = key.split('-')
                        qu_question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
                        user_answer = UserAnswer(student=request.user,
                                                 question=qu_question,
                                                 answer=value.strip(),
                                                 exercise_submission=exercise_submission)
                        user_answer.save()

                    # Get Multichoice Questions
                    if key.startswith('mcq'):
                        prefix, question_id, choice_counter = key.split('-')
                        mc_question = MultiChoiceQuestion.objects.get(pk=question_id)
                        mc_option_selected = MultiChoiceQuestionOption.objects.get(question=mc_question, content=value.strip())
                        mc_answer = MultiChoiceUserSubmittedAnswer(
                                                    student=request.user,
                                                    question=mc_question,
                                                    selected_choice=mc_option_selected,
                                                    exercise_submission=exercise_submission)
                        mc_answer.save()

                    # Get Essay Questions
                    if key.startswith('eq'):
                        prefix, question_id = key.split('-')
                        essay_question = EssayQuestion.objects.get(pk=question_id)
                        try:
                            essay_answer = EssayUserAnswer.objects.get(student=request.user, question=essay_question)
                        except EssayUserAnswer.DoesNotExist:
                            essay_answer = EssayUserAnswer(student=request.user,
                                                 question=essay_question,
                                                 answer=value.strip(),
                                                 exercise_submission=exercise_submission)
                            essay_answer.save()

            # Update the user progress
            progress = StudentLessonProgress.objects.get(student=request.user, lesson=lesson)
            progress.status = COMPLETED
            progress.done_percent = 100 # Incrementing percentage at this stage to make it 100
            progress.save()

            messages.success(request, "Thank you! Your answer submission has been saved. Click on the Answers tab to reveal the correct answers.")
        else:
            form = LessonExerciseForm()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you! Your answer submission was NOT saved because you had previously done this exercise.")

        return HttpResponseRedirect( '{0}#answers'.format(reverse('learn_lesson',
                                    kwargs={
                                    'form':form,
                                    'course_slug':lesson.module.course.slug,
                                    'module_slug':lesson.module.slug,
                                    'lesson_slug':lesson.slug}
                                    )))
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class ExerciseSubmission(models.Model):
    """ Data Model representing a student's exercise Submission. """
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='The Student', related_name='exercise_submissions')
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, verbose_name=_("Exercise"))
    #lesson = get_model('jm_lms.apps.courses.models', 'Lesson') #models.ForeignKey(Lesson, verbose_name='Lesson')
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Exercise Submission")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Exercise Submissions")


class BaseQuestion(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, verbose_name=_("Exercise"))
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name="Topic Box", blank=True, null=True)
    expected_answer = models.TextField(verbose_name="Expected Answer", blank=True, null=True, help_text=_("How the learner should answer the question. Shown after the question has been answered."))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(BaseQuestion):
    num_of_expected_answers = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name=_("Number of expected answers"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("List Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("List Questions")


class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    """
    Response given by a user
    """
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='The Student', related_name='exercise_answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name=_("Question"))
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    answered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    exercise_submission = models.ForeignKey(ExerciseSubmission, verbose_name=_("Exercise Submission"), blank=True, null=True)
    # status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Answer Status", choices=USER_ANSWER_STATUS, default=NOT_PUBLISHED, help_text='Enable user answer reference in the next Lesson')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)
        verbose_name = _("User Answer to List Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("User Answers to List Question")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer


class MultiChoiceQuestion(BaseQuestion):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Multiple Choice Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Multiple Choice Questions")

    def check_if_correct(self, guess):
        answer = MultiChoiceQuestionOption.objects.get(id=guess)

        if answer.correct is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_answers(self):
        return MultiChoiceQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=self)

    def get_answers_list(self):
        return [(answer.id, answer.content) for answer in MultiChoiceQuestionOption.objects.filter(question=self)]


class MultiChoiceQuestionOption(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(MultiChoiceQuestion, verbose_name=_("Question"))
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000,
                               blank=False,
                               help_text=_("Enter the answer text that you want displayed"),
                               verbose_name=_("Answer Content"))
    correct = models.BooleanField(blank=False,
                                  default=False,
                                  help_text=_("Is this a correct answer?"),
                                  verbose_name=_("Correct"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("MultiChoice Option")
        verbose_name_plural = _("MultiChoice Options")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content


class MultiChoiceUserSubmittedAnswer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='The Student', related_name='exercise_submitted_choice')
    question = models.ForeignKey(MultiChoiceQuestion, verbose_name=_("Question"))
    selected_choice = models.ForeignKey(MultiChoiceQuestionOption, verbose_name=_("Question"))
    answered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    exercise_submission = models.ForeignKey(ExerciseSubmission, verbose_name=_("Exercise Submission"), blank=True, null=True)
    # status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Answer Status", choices=USER_ANSWER_STATUS, default=NOT_PUBLISHED, help_text='Enable user answer reference in the next Lesson')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("MultiChoice Submitted User Answer")
        verbose_name_plural = _("MultiChoice Submitted User Answers")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.selected_choice.content


class EssayQuestion(BaseQuestion):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Essay Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Essay Questions")


class EssayUserAnswer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='The Student', related_name='exercise_essay_answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(EssayQuestion, verbose_name=_("Question"))
    answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    answered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    exercise_submission = models.ForeignKey(ExerciseSubmission, verbose_name=_("Exercise Submission"), blank=True, null=True)
    # status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Answer Status", choices=USER_ANSWER_STATUS, default=NOT_PUBLISHED, help_text='Enable user answer reference in the next Lesson')



# class TableExerciseQuestion(BaseQuestion):
#     class Meta:
#         verbose_name = _("Table Exercise Question")
#         verbose_name_plural = _("Table Exercise Questions")
# 
# 
# class TableExercise(models.Model):
#     """
#     Model to enable lesson developer to add lesson exercise fields headers ,description e.t.c
#     """
#     question = models.ForeignKey(TableExerciseQuestion, verbose_name=_("Question"))
#     field_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#     field_occurrence = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name=_("Number of expected fields"))
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class LessonExerciseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = [MultiChoiceQuestion, ExerciseSubmission, EssayQuestion]
    fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem while dealing with different issue. But I think your problem is the same.

[link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159752/dynamically-added-row-to-inline-formset-not-reflected-in-the-post-request-in-vie)

Basically the problem was the html code. I would suggest that you verify your generated html code in browser and check if the form tags are closed properly. It might be the case that form tags are closed earlier than your data is coming later in html and it wouldn't be submitted. Check generated html.