# Dynamic django inline_formset using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I was searching on working examples for django inline_formset with javascript and found this post [Add a dynamic form to a django formset using javascript in a right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260987/add-a-dynamic-form-to-a-django-formset-using-javascript-in-a-right-way). In the process, I tried to convert the Jquery portion into pure javascript? I have tried

```
const btnAddMoreImg = document.querySelector('#add-image-button');
btnAddMoreImg.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let count = document.querySelector('#item-images').children.length;
    let tmplMarkup = document.querySelector('#images-template').innerHTML;
    let compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
    
    $('#item-images').append(compiledTmpl); // how to convert this to pure javascript?

    // update form count
    document.querySelector('#id_images-TOTAL_FORMS').setAttribute('value', count + 1);
})
```

This works but there is still this jquery code `$('#item-images').append(compiledTmpl)` which I tried to change to `document.querySelector('#item-images').append(compiledTmpl)`, but the end result would be a string of html tags instead of a new form added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working using the insertRow() method of a table.

```
    let newRow = itemContainer.insertRow(itemContainer.rows.length);
    newRow.outerHTML = compiledTmpl;
```